# Distribution of Gaussian projection on the unit sphere

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $X$ be a Gaussian distribution in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with mean $\mu = 0$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$.

Is there a known pdf of $\frac{X}{\|X\|}$? (An approximation will do as well).

Comment: This is not easy to do...I have been interested in a similar problem before, and eventually resorted to simulation. For $X/Y$ you can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution , but then $X$ and $Y$ must be independent, which here is not the case. So in the end you must resort to trying to find some nasty surface integral for each component you are trying to normalize, which even for the case of $n=2$ proved to be very challenging.

Comment: You may wish to check out this paper https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.ba/1453211962